# How to disable Bootstrap DatePicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

Having trouble disabling the [DatePickerhere](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Im able to disable the input field but the calender glyphicon will still open the picker when pressed.

I've tried setting the disabled and readonly property of the picker but that only applies to the input field. I can't disable to glyphicon to disable the control completely.

**QUESTION:** How do i disable the control completely ?

Here's what i've tried so far:

```
<div class="input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="kalib_dato" disabled readonly />
 <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dateRangePicker')
        .datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            startDate: '01/01/2010',
            endDate: '12/30/2020',
            autoclose: true,
            language: 'da',
            enableOnReadonly: false
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE:** Iv'e come as far that i am able to initialize it on demand. Now i would really like do un-initialize it again.

Iv'e tried calling $(document).off('.datepicker.data-api'); as stated in the docs but it's not working for me.

Heres a fiddle to demonstrate my troubles: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12438/)

Comment: Why do you want to remove that ability? Just don't attach the datepicker when the field is disabled is maybe a more simple solution

Comment: @acrobat The component is by default disabled. If I change the selected value of a dropdown it will be enabled. So i need to be able to enable and disable it accordingly

Comment: Then the best thing you could do is, have on change on the dropdown and when it changes (and the datepicker should be available) attach the datepicker to the field ( `$('#fieldId').datepicker({//customOptions}); `

Comment: @acrobat I've tried adding a button to disable the data-api of the picker but it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12417/

Comment: I've posted an answer that looks like a fix for your problem!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By the comments you gave this looks like a suitable solution for you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#state').on('change', function() {
       if ($(this).val() == 'on') {
           $('#dateRangePicker').datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                startDate: '01/01/2010',
                endDate: '12/30/2020',
                autoclose: true,
                language: 'da',
                enableOnReadonly: false
            });
            $('#dateRangePicker > .form-control').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#dateRangePicker').datepicker('remove');
            $('#dateRangePicker > .form-control').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
    $('#dateRangePicker > .form-control').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12440/) for a working example!

Comment: if dateRangePicker as a class selector i wont work why

Comment: @srinivasgowda check my answer, you may need to modify your selector as I did.

Comment: thanks `.datepicker("remove")` worked for me. for some reason, `.datepicker("destroy")` as suggested by other answers in other questions didnt work +1

Answer (score 0):

You can control the button click separately to the datepicker as long as the datepicker initialization targets the input.

Target the input `#kalib_dato` with `.datepicker()` instead of the `input-group#dateRangePicker`.

Add an id to the button span... such as 'kalib_spano' then the button can conditionally show the datepicker.

```
$("#kalib_spano").click(function () {
    if (!someDisabledCondition) {
        // trigger the datepicker
        $("#kalib_dato").datepicker("show");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone else finds this that is using the angular plugin [ng2-datetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetime) which uses [bootstrap-timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) and bootstrap-datepicker under the hood, I was able to tweak acrobat's answer for this case.  I had to use a different selector, but otherwise acrobat's solution was spot on for my case.  My class **custom-date-time-picker** is applied at the component level for the plugin.  I am only using the time-picker part of the plugin, having disabled the datepicker.

`<datetime class="custom-date-time-picker" [datepicker]="false" [timepicker]="timePickerOptions"></datetime>`

`$('.custom-date-time-picker .form-control').prop('disabled', true);
$('.custom-date-time-picker .form-control').prop('disabled', false);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$("#YourDateID").prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score -4):

Don't initialize datepicker in javascript. If you dont need the datepicker.

Just use below HTML code.

```
<div class="input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="kalib_dato" disabled readonly />
<span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
```

Comment: What have you changed with your code .. seems like a copy of my html from above ? .

Comment: yes the same code only. But remove the javascript to disable the datepicker completely.

Comment: @katamaraju are u kidding?