# How to disable bootstrap date picker from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to disable bootstrap date picker from the javascript code. I am using asp.net application.

```js
//jquery script  
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  clearBtn: true,
  todayHighlight: true
}).datepicker('update', new Date());

var v1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtdatepicker.ClientID %>');
v1.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly"); //this code make textbox readonly:(  

//ive tried this
$(document).off('.datepicker.data-api');
```

```html
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-MM-yyy">
  <input class="form-control" id="txtdatepicker" type="text" runat="server" readonly="readonly" />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i   class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span> 
</div>
```

I tried the solutions give below but the calender still pops up and the date 
in the date picker text box changes.

Comment: Try `v1.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");` or `v1.setAttribute("disabled", true);`

Comment: what datepicker are you using? show how you initializer it: - $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker() ??

Comment: `v1.setAttribute("data-provide", "")` will kill it for good :) to turn it back `v1.setAttribute("data-provide", "datepicker")`

Comment: @BG101 im using $('#datepicker').datepicker()

Comment: @GuruprasadRao v1.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly"); using this code i can disable text box only not the calender popup.i need to prevent calender

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Bootstrap DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756579/how-to-disable-bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 3):

try this:-

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ enableOnReadonly: false });
```

[enableonreadonly](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#enableonreadonly)

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
$('#your-element-id').datepicker("remove");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this . **May not be a good approach but works**

```js
$(".DatePicker").datepicker({
  Format: "m-dd-yy",
  autoclose: true,
}).on('show', function() {
  if ($(this).attr('readonly')) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide')
  }
})

$('#disable').click(function() {
  $(".DatePicker").attr('readonly', 'readonly')
});
$('#enable').click(function() {
  $(".DatePicker").removeAttr('readonly')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <input type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="DatePicker" />
</div>
<input type='button' value='Disable the Datepicker' id='disable' />
<input type='button' value='Enable the Datepicker' id='enable' />
```

Comment: Thank you guys, i really apreciate your time. my problem remains the same so i changed my  requirement slightly  to overcome this issue.